# Doubt in a step of solving a system of eqn. under constraint.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a function $$F(x,a)=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
f(x)-a  \\ 
g_1(x)\\
\vdots \\ g_m(x)\end{array} \right] $$   where $f\in C^1(U,\mathbb R)$ where $U$ is open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $g_i's$ have equality constraints s.t. $g_i(x)=0$ and $f(x)=a$.

now

> if I'm given that the jacobian of $F(x_0,a)$ is non-singular and I define for some neighborhood $U$ about $(x_0,a)$ ,s.t. $$\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n-m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$$  s.t. $\phi(u) = (x_u,a_u)$ which satisfies $F(x_u,a_u) = 0 ~ \textrm{ for all } ~u \in U$

How does jacobian of $F(x_0,a)$ is non-singular   ensure that I can get an open image for $\phi$ around $(x_0,a)$ ...

Please help me with this doubt...
 Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a consequence of the Local inversion theorem: for any $(x,a)\in U$, there is a local inverse defined on an open set $O$ containing $F(x,a)$.

Now use the fact that if $h$ is continuous, for any open set $O, h^{-1}(O)$ is an open set as well.